# optimizing the double loop in the python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for i in df.index:
     y = df["id"][i]
     x = "/content/"
     z = "/*.jpg"
     PATH = x + y + z
     for q in glob.glob(PATH):
       X_train.append(load_image(q)) #load image is a fun of reading images
       y_train.append(1)
```

can we optimize this furthermore?
because when I run this code i got the error -: "running out of memory"

Comment: imports are missing, please provide an mre as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example guidelines on how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: What is `load_image` ?

Comment: I don't think the nested loops are your problem. It looks like you're trying to load more data (images?) into memory than your system can cope with

Comment: @azro basically it is reading the image and adding to the list.

Comment: @OlvinRoght oh, ok! then i think i cant do optimize it more.